# Favicon disappear on navigation in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, favicon

I am using IE 11. Favicon for my site is working fine in landing page. But when I am navigating to other route the it is disappeared. Then if I press F5 then favicon appeared again. it is happening for all the route. One I reload that route the it is visible for that particular route all the time.

I am using below approach

link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"

If I keep the favicon in the root folder of the site in IIS then it is working fine. But there can be many application under one site. So can't go with this approach.

Comment: Is it happening just on IE11?

Comment: Yes Vinod, it is working fine in Chrome.

Comment: Did you fixed it? I'm getting the same behaviour in IE11 and Safari 6, but works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hi EdSF did you solve this issue?

Comment: Did anyone solve it ?

Comment: Did anyone got the resolution ? or any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in IE and Edge:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9383036/

Don't believe the status 'Fixed' — it is not fixed, as mentioned in the comments.